# How to use Regex to lowercase catalogue values without any logic codes

Tags: sql, regex, uppercase, lowercase, nsregularexpression

For a loan domain we pass some catalogue values eg. if a customer is primary or secondary customer like that. So i need to check the values irrespective of uppercase, lowercase, camelcase. Software which i  am using will accept only regex codes not any Java, js codes (it is different scripting). I am trying to convert only with regexp but still getting error.

```
If catalogue_value ~"(/A-Z/)" then
Catalogue_value ~"/l"
Endif
```

As i am learning regex as of now still figuring for correct expressions to use.
Kindly please tell me correct format to use regex to change into lowercase / uppercase

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your problem you want to search without worrying about the case, for example the data is `Paul`, and you want to find this record searching by `PAUL`, `paul`, `PaUl`, etc?

One common to technique to do that is to put both sides all in upper or lower case, without regex, for example, in javascript:

```
"Paul".toLowerCase() === "paUL".toLowerCase()
```

In SQL:

```
select case when LOWER('Paul') = LOWER('paUL') then 1 else 0 end
```